# Работа с векторами

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть такая функция:

```
void clear2(std::vector<int>* vec){
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec->end(); *it = 0; --it){
        vec->pop_back();
    }
}
```

На vec->end() вываливается с ошибкой. В отладчике:

```
>Debug.Print vec
0x00d8f9a0 { size=8 }
[size]: 8
[capacity]: 9
[0]: 1
[1]: 0
[2]: 0
[3]: 0
[4]: 0
[5]: 0
[6]: 0
[7]: 0
[Базовое представление]: 0x00d8f9a0 {...}
>Debug.Print it
-842150451
[ptr]: 0x00ebba08 {-842150451}
[Базовое представление]: 0x00d8f878 {...}
```

Из-за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

end указывает на элемент следующий за последним.

```
a[5];
[0][1][2][3][4][5][это end()]
```